# Exchange 2003 - Send email to a specific external server error

Tags: windows, exchange-server

I am using a small business 2003 server with Microsoft exchange 2003!! Both of them are fully updated to their newest versions!! However I am having a problem!! When I am trying to send an email from a PC in our domain (using outlook) to a specific external server it doesn't reach and I am getting this error message:
Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.
Subject: test
Sent: 2/6/2015 10:17

```
The following recipients cannot be reached:
info@kekdei.gr on 2/6/2015 10:16
The recipient could not be processed because it would violate the security policy in force <ipa237.225.tellas.gr #5.7.0smtp;550 5.7.0 550 Your server IP address
[my address] does not have a valid reverse DNS entry [ipa237.225.tellas.gr].
```

I tried to send an email to that address using Hotmail and it reached the destination!!! any ideas?